# Vanishing Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

So let us assume that we have a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its first fundamental form $ds^2=E(u)du^2+G(v)dv^2$. Does its Gaussian curvature vanish? The answer is supposed to be yes, and I tried computing the Gaussian curvature using the intrinsic formula $K=R_{121}^\ell g_{\ell2}/g$ where $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor, but I wasn't able to get everything to cancel. I was hoping someone could do the computation so I can identify where I'm going wrong.

**EDIT** Here is what I got. Let us assume the chart were working in is $x(u,v)$.
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma_{11}^1&=\frac{\partial_1E}{2}E^{-1}\\
\Gamma_{12}^1&=0\\
\Gamma_{22}^1&=0\\
\Gamma_{11}^2&=\langle x_{11},x_2\rangle g^{22}\\
\Gamma_{12}^2&=0\\
\Gamma_{22}^2&=\frac{\partial_2G}{2}G^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

Using the intrinsic formula I got 
$$K=\frac{\partial_2\langle x_{11},x_2\rangle G}{G^2}-\frac{\langle x_{11},x_2\rangle \langle x_{22},x_2\rangle}{G^2}$$

Comment: usually, at this site, you show what you have done and others might be willing to comment on it.

Comment: I'm adding it in right now. Just wanted to post the problem first.

Comment: I don't think $K$ will vanish in general. Why do you expect $K=0$?

Comment: The Brioschi formula gives the answer quite succinctly.

Comment: I guess since the metric tensor has coefficients matching up in terms with the variables of the adjacent forms that the surfaces "looks" like $\mathbb{R}^2$, so one would expect the curvature to vanish. At least this is what I think on an intuitive level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you should use [Brioschi Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrioschiFormula.html). Since $E=E(u)$ and $G=G(v)$ and $F=0$, hence by the above formula, Gaussian Curvature, $K=0$.